# $4$ balls, $4$ bags probability of corresponding

Tags: probability

If there exists $4$ balls which re named ball$1$,ball$2$,ball$3$, ball$4$ and four bags, named bag$1$, bag$2$,bag$3$, bag$4$, which is the probability that ball$1$ corresponds to bag$1$, ball$2$ corresponds to bag$2$, ball$3$ corresponds to bag$3$, ball$4$ corresponds to bag$4$?

thanks :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'corresponds'?

Comment: ball 1 goes in bag 1, ball 2 goes in bag 2, ball 3 goes in bag 3, ball 4 goes  in bag4

Comment: There are $4!=24$ orderings here and only one of them is the right one. This gives a probability of $\frac{1}{24}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Each ball goes in the corresponding bag

It is
$$
P=\frac{1}{4!}=\frac{1}{4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}=\frac{1}{24}
$$
since $n$ balls goes in $n$ bags in $n!$ ways. Read about the factorial. This is very basic in that subject!!!

### NO ball goes in its corresponding bag

If what you meant is that NONE of them goes into the bag having the same enumeration this can be solved considering a permutation as a product of cycles. So we have a permutation in $S_4$ which is a map mapping the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to itself, for instance:
$$
\left(\matrix{1&2&3&4\\4&3&2&1}\right)
$$
mapping 1 to 4 (since 1 is above 4 in the notation used) and so on. Such permutations can be written uniquely as distinct cycles. For instance the above permutation can be written as
$$
(1\ 4)(2\ 3)
$$
which is a product of two $2$-cycles, namely $(1\ 4)$ which is a $2$-cycle swapping 1 and 4 and $(2\ 3)$ a $2$-cycle swapping 2 and 3. To have another example $(1\ 2\ 3)$ maps 1 to 2 to 3 to 1 so it cycles the numbers 1, 2 and 3.

In this context what you are asking is the number of permutations in $S_4$ that fixes NO element of the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$. It is easily seen that this has either to be a $4$-cycle or a product of $2$-cycles.

There are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to choose one $2$-cycle and by this choice the other $2$-cycle is also determined to cycle the other two elements. But this leads to an overcount by a factor $2$ since you could choose $(1\ 4)$ first then $(2\ 3)$ or the other way around, but $(1\ 4)(2\ 3)$ and $(2\ 3)(1\ 4)$ is the exact same permutation. So only $3$ distinct $2$-cycle products exist.

Also there are $4!=24$ ways to write a $4$-cycle, but
$$
(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)=(4\ 1\ 2\ 3)=(3\ 4\ 1\ 2)=(2\ 3\ 4\ 1)
$$
so this is an overcount by a factor 4. So in fact only $6$ distinct $4$-cycles exist.

All together we have $3+6=9$ permutations mapping NO ball to its corresponding bag. So the answer is then:
$$
Q=\frac{9}{24}
$$
as the probability of having NONE of the balls corresponding to the bag.

Comment: OK, Now I want to ask you, which is the probability as the balls not to correspond. is it $$\frac{23}{24}$$?

Comment: @Iuli: Indeed! Unless you mean the probability that none of them correspond...

Comment: a little help please. Which is the probability that none of the balls not to correspond?

Comment: Advice1: reformulate your question. Advice2: $24$ is not such a big number, so write all orderings down and check out. You could also ask a new question concerning $n$ balls and bags. Then your counting will probably be made unnecessary.

Comment: I don't need unuseful information. Yon can give this information to another people. If you can help me, I will thanks you, if you can't it is ok, too.

Comment: but I want to ask you why the total posibilities are $4!$ and no $4^4$? thanks

Comment: @Iuli: Allright, good question. I did not catch that. It was just me being simple minded assuming you would put one ball into each bag. If more balls are allowed to go into the same bag the first probability will indeed be $P=\frac{1}{4^4}$ and the second will be $Q=\frac{3^4}{4^4}$.

Comment: @Iuli: Then I would say it becomes much less of a combinatorial problem. You could write $$p=P(\mbox{ball x goes into bag x})=\frac{1}{4}$$ and then $P=p^4$ and $Q=(1-p)^4$.

Answer (score 2):

There is, however, a more elementary solution to find the probability of no ball corresponding to its correct box.

If we let A be the event that the ball A is in the correct box, and 
similarly B is event that the ball B is in the correct box, then $P(A \cup B \cup C \cup D)$ would give us the probability of at least 1 ball corresponding to its correct box. If we substract it from 1, we'd find the probability that none of the balls correspond.

$1 - P(A \cup B \cup C \cup D) = 1 - [P(A)+P(B)+P(C)+P(D)-P(A\cap B) - P (A \cap C) - P (A \cap D) - P (B \cap C) - P (B \cap D) - P (C \cap D) + P(A \cap B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap D) + P(A \cap C \cap D) + P(B \cap C \cap D) - P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D)]$

Because $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=P(D)$ whole equation could be simplified to

$1 - [4P(A) - 6P (A \cap B) + 4P(A \cap B \cap C) - P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D)]$

$= 1 - [4\cdot\frac{1}{4}-6\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+4\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1}] = \frac{9}{24}$

Comment: OK, I can see that this requires much less preliminary knowledge! I would not say the long lines with all the $P$'s look nice, but in fact they are not that bad!

Comment: Yeah, but once you learn the inclusion-exlusion principle you don't need to write them P's over and over again. You can just use the formula 1/2! - 1/3! + 1/4! + ... + ((-1)^n)/n!